# Is it posible to get a regex from attr() in CSS?

Tags: html, css, regex, css-selectors

I am trying to make my own CSS grid framework to understand it better. Something I wish to do is to specify how many rows-columns something spans. To do this, I would like to use some regular expressions.

At the moment, I currently have this HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item-1 span1">Item 1</div>
  <div class="item-2">Item 2</div>
  <div class="item-3">Item 3</div>
  <div class="item-4">Item 4</div>
  <div class="item-5">Item 5</div>
  <div class="item-6">Item 6</div>
  <div class="item-7">Item 7</div>
  <div class="item-8">Item 8</div>
  <div class="item-9">Item 9</div>
  <div class="item-10">Item 10</div>
  <div class="item-11">Item 11</div>
  <div class="item-12">Item 12</div>
  <div class="item-13">Item 13</div>
  <div class="item-14">Item 14</div>
  <div class="item-15">Item 15</div>
  <div class="item-16">Item 16</div>
</div>
```

With this CSS:

```
@import "reset.css";
:root{
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  --box-color: #eee;}
body{
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;}

.wrapper{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

* [class*=span]{
  background: var(--box-color);
}

* [class*=span]::before{
  content: attr(class);
}
```

At the moment the CSS only sets the background to a grey color if it has span as a class. I would then like to `grid-row: <span-(number)>`.

Is it possible to do this with pure CSS or would I have to use JavaScript as well?
If I can use CSS only, how would I be able to do this?

Comment: No, one can't do that w/o script. And at the moment, `attr()` will return a `string`, hence won't be able to do anything but render a value as such from one of its attributes.

Comment: I don't understand your question, but regex doesn't exist in html and css, so you would have to use javascript.

Comment: @AniketG Basically my question asks if I can get a certain value from a HTML attribute. For example, If I had `div.span1`, I would want to get the number '1' using CSS without JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to get the class of an HTML element with pure CSS. To do it with JavaScript, simply do:

```js
console.log(document.getElementById("element").getAttribute("class"));
```

```html
<p class="test" id="element">value</p>
```

Or in my opinion, you can use a simpler method using jQuery:

```js
console.log($("#element").attr("class"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="test" id="element">value</p>
```

Comment: The attr(class) shown in the question *is* how you do it with CSS. The question is asking how to do something a little more advanced than that.

Comment: I was going based off his comment. The question is confusing

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible with CSS; as LGSon says, `attr()` will give you the entire attribute value as a single string, and you won't be able to perform any string manipulation with it.

The closest you can get is putting the number in its own custom data attribute, but of course that does mean bloating your markup with one more attribute on every item, all for the sake of making a grid system work.

Answer (score -5):

CSS is made to style the html tags. It is not possible to do any mathematical task in CSS. For any increment or decrements or any calculation you need to use javascript.

Comment: Are you sure about this? You can use `calc` `abs` etc to do maths and you can also use transition and keyframes to change values. Also, you can use SGV inside CSS to animate things by incrementing certain values.